# Can I add a function in a Text Box and display only the results?

Tags: excel

Can I add a function  in a Text Box and display only the results?

My function: ="Avg Open Time ALL: " & ROUND(AVERAGE(CombinedBugData[Time 2 Fix]),0) &" Days"

I am hoping that this can be done without VBA

Comment: you could get this pretty easily with a message box, and putting a button on the worksheet to make the message box pop up (This is VBA though..., but the code is very simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what I think you want by using "Shapes" under the "Insert Tab":

[image: Insert - Shapes]

I created a simple rectangle, which probably most represents a "text box".  Then all you have to do is click on the rectangle and in the formula bar type in a cell reference.  Here is a "Hello World" example using `=A1` as the formula:

[image: Type in formula]

You use any cell reference there and it will update when the cell changes.

Hopefully that meets the requirements of what you want to achieve.

Comment: The Text Box only took a reference and not a full formula, but that works for what I was trying to do.  Thanks.

Comment: @SammyB You are very correct I didn't even realize that, I changed the wording on my answer to reflect that you can only reference cells instead of using a direct formula in the shape